# Python list comprehension for if-else statements

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way to express the following code through Python list comprehension?

```
newlist = []
for i,j in enumerate(old_list):
if i==0:
    newlist.append(j*2+1)
else:
    newlist.append(j*2)
```

Comment: Use a conditional expression: `[j*2+1 if not i else j*2 for i, j in enumerate(old_list)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why not?

```
[j*2+1 if i==0 else j*2 for i, j in enumerate(old_list)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with an inline `if`, like this:

```
newlist = [j * 2 + (1 if i == 0 else 0) for i, j in enumerate(old_list)]
```